# Как обработать такой формат даты?

Tags: javascript

Сторонний сервис отдает дату в таком формате:

```
/Date(1332446400000+0300)/
```

Как на `JavaScript` ее можно обработать в нормальную?
Понятно, что можно в `moment.js` в объект передать `Dat(*)` и вернет то, что надо, однако:

```
typeof /Date(1332446400000+0300)/ == "object" // true
```

Как мне избавиться от лишнего, чтобы я мог спокойно передать в `moment` такой формат?
Причем мне нужно предварительно проверять переменную на предмет принадлежности к Дате.

```
/Date(1332446400000+0300)/ instanceof Date; // false
```

Comment: var a = /Date(1332446400000+0300)/
a.getDay() // ошибка!

Comment: var a = /Date(1332446400000+0300)/
new Date(parseInt(a.match(/\d+/)[0],10))
так пишет ошибку

var a = /Date(1332446400000+0300)/
new Date(parseInt(/Date(1332446400000+0300)/.match(/\d+/)[0],10))
так работает, но мне ведь нужно определить сначала, что a это тип Data, у меня в a попадают разные значения

Comment: естественно, читай внимательнее ответы, и во-первых сервис отдает строку, поэтому когда пробуешь у себя окружай кавычками _"/Date(1332446400000+0300)/"_ в противном случае ты пытаешься работать с регулярным выражением.

Comment: ааа, понял, спасибо) напишите ответ, отмечу

Comment: var a = "/Date(1332446400000+0300)/"; 
a.replace(new RegExp("/", 'g'), '');
а как мне теперь проверить, что это тип Date? он ведь просто строкой считает это

Comment: `a = "/Date(1332446400000+0300)/"; a.replace(new RegExp("/", 'g'), '');` - что это за код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Бескомпромиссный парсинг без регулярных выражений! : )

Гипотеза: то, что в скобках – миллисекунды от начала Unix эпохи и смещение временнОй зоны в виде `+HHMM` (и может быть `-HHMM`).

Выбираем всё внутри скобок, разбиваем по знаку "+" или "–", конструируем объект `Date` из этого времени, вычитая его timezone offset (переводим HH и MM в миллисекунды).

```js
var myDate = parseDate("/Date(1332446400000+0300)/"); // из ответа сервера

document.body.innerText = myDate.toString();

function parseDate( response) {
  if( response.substr(0,6) !== '/Date(' || response.substr(-2) !== ')/') {
    throw "Bad date format"; // какой-то не тот формат
  }

  var D = new Date(), parts, sign;

  if( !!~response.indexOf('+')) {
    sign = 1;
    parts = response.substr(6, response.length-8).split('+');
  } else if( !!~response.indexOf('-')) {
    sign = -1;
    parts = response.substr(6, response.length-8).split('-');
  } else {
    throw "No timezone offset";
  }

  if( parts[1].length !== 4) throw "Bad timezone offset";

  D.setTime(
    parseInt( parts[0], 10) 
    - sign * 36E5 * parseInt( parts[1].substr(0,2), 10)
    - sign * 6E4 * parseInt( parts[1].substr(2,2), 10)
  );
  
  return D;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Такой формат `Date.parse` не скушает, ибо некорректно.
Лучше вырезать миллисекунды, подставить как число в конструктор `Date` и, возможно, поиграться с сдвигом `UTC`.
Правда с последним в `JS` проблемы, можно попробовать костылём.

```js
let str = '/Date(1332446400000+0300)/'; // Ваша строка
// Выдираем длинное число миллисекунд и UTC
let [, time, utc] = /Date\((\d+)((?:\+|-)0\d00)/.exec(str);

// Валидный объект Date
// Сначала создаём объект через мс
// Потом возвращаем GTM представление и подменяем на нужный пояс, получается что-то типа:
// Thu, 22 Mar 2012 20:00:00 GMT+0300
// Так Date.parse поймёт и переведёт в нужный пояс
console.info(new Date(new Date(+time).toGMTString().replace('GMT', `GMT${utc}`)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/Date(1332446400000+0300)/
```

Это регулярное выражение. Попробуйте заменить все слэши

```
"/Date(1332446400000+0300)/".replace(/\//g,'');
```

На выходе будет

```
"Date(1332446400000+0300)"
```

Как один из вариантов далее пронать результат через eval.

```js
var output = document.querySelector('div');
function validateDate(input){
var date;
try {
    date = new Date(eval(input.replace(/\//g,'')));
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(date) !== "[object Date]" || isNaN(+date)) throw new TypeError;
} catch(e){
    return false;
}
return date;  
};

output.innerHTML = validateDate('/Date(1332446400000+0300)/');
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Как один из вариантов, прогнать это через eval;

Comment: var a = eval("Date(1332446400000+0300)"); a instanceof Date
// false
Как мне проверить, что переменная принадлежит к типу Date?

Comment: new Date(eval("Date(1332446400000+0300)")) instanceof Date // true

Comment: спасибо)) но мне так каждое новое значение переменной проверять тогда придется?

Comment: Обновил код в ответе.
В случае если дата не валидна, вернет false, в противном вернет саму дату(объект Date).